# components of a symbol name in objdump output

Tags: c++, linux, elf, objdump

I'm trying to use objdump to compare two different versions of a binary file and was wondering if anyone knew how to interpret the symbol name from the following line of my objdump output:

```
102b33bc l     O .rodata    00000058 ThisIsMyStruct::ThisIsMyStruct()::C.24
```

This output was generated using the following command:

```
objdump -t -C -r -w --special-syms my.bin > my.bin.txt
```

My problem is that two different versions of my.bin have the same line, but one has C.24 at the end and the other has C.12 at the end.

What does the C.# represent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It represents whatever your compiler wants it to represent. [Symbol name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is entirely compiler specific, and will even vary with the version of the compiler. Just the other day I was surprised when certain gcc compiler options also resulted in different symbol mangling. That was fun.

A search of http://gcc.gnu.org does not seem to find any documentation for gcc's name mangling. A general Google search was also not very enlightening.

Comment: GCC's name mangling for external symbols follows the Itanium C++ ABI: https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling. But here the symbol is local, so all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that two different versions of my.bin have the same line, but one has C.24 at the end and the other has C.12 at the end.

This *can not* be your problem: this symbol has local linkage (the `l` part), and isn't visible outside of the object file in which it is defined.

The symbol likely represents some string literal, e.g. `"foo\n"` in `printf("foo\n")`. It is also likely that the literal is defined on line 12 in one case, and on line 24 in another case (though this is far from guaranteed).